# Creating a dependent drop down list on each row depending on a value in that same row

Tags: google-sheets, drop-down-menu, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to create a column of dropdown lists which changes based on a value in the same row of the adjacent column. I have created a spreadsheet with an example of what I am trying to achieve with the data arranged in a similar way to my actual spreadsheet. In this sheet, I would like all of column B (Cities) in Main to be dropdown lists which change depending on the Country value in the adjacent cell. So, for example, cell B2 (Cities adjacent to UK) should contain a drop-down of all the values in A2:A4 (cities in the UK) of the Country List sheet.

Here is the example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19pszTsJDNlc7G2lgacyOhLydHTAhkQXosM6PCL0VvrI/edit?usp=sharing

I have tried using the IF function with indirect, but it cannot work with my data because I need the drop-down lists in multiple rows.

I don't mind using a script to do this.

Comment: It may be easier to accomplish this with a script than formulas. But [Prashant](https://infoinspired.com/about-me/) has a nice tutorial [here](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/dynamic-dependent-drop-down-list-in-google-sheets/) on it using formulas.

Comment: Thanks, I am open to using script so how would I do it with script?

Comment: Folks here tend to frown upon such requests. :-) You need to show some sort of attempt at writing scripts. And then others can help fix the code. But FWIW I wrote a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@dogmatix/google-sheets-data-validation-using-google-apps-script-735023fb9fb8?sk=e4e224bc5dcf6e531514e474576cb83b) on how to do this using a script.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much that's perfect!!

Comment: When I tried to incorporate this into my spreadsheet it gave me an error of "TypeError: Cannot read property "value" from undefined. (line 3, file "Code")" for the first line of code. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Also, I don't know if it is relevant but the 'Country' list in my actual spreadsheet will be pasted in from another spreadsheet via a script, so the onEdit function may not be suitable in my case.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this but you will need some helper columns:

[image: 0]

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("Country list!"&
 ADDRESS(2, MATCH(A2, 'Country list'!$1:$1, 0))&":"&
 ADDRESS(5, MATCH(A2, 'Country list'!$1:$1, 0)))))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RKVhm95R83uKxsdhByzngQI8-r7PH2Z0SnPfqfCPoY8/copy)